# Setting locale shows two different languages

Tags: android, locale

I have an application in which I set the locale from where to pick the language programmatically.

The screen from where I choose the language has some buttons with text and the menu in the action bar.

Sometimes, I don't know the reason or how to reproduce it, the buttons have the right language which is set in the application but when I press on the menu button, the menu is shown in the language of the phone.

I haven't found this problem online, do you know what can go wrong? I have all the translations in the xml files and it all works well most of the time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().trim().equals(""))
    return "en";
else
    return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Return language. After this create a folder in res -> values for English values-fr for French.

Comment: I don't understand you? I already have all the resources for all the translations and I already set the locales for picking the right language.

Comment: You want set your application Locale value based on your button selection